# How to use a existed event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am working a problem which is about delegate and event. I am a newbid in this aspect. I don't know how to call the event.

Would some tell me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply some more information.  Are you trying to raise an existing event?  Are you trying assign an event handler?  Please specify with code examples if you can.

Comment: What type/kind of event are you talking about? Can you explain problem domain?

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

The event can be invoked in the class in which it is declared. First you'll usually want to check if your event is null.

```
if (MyEvent != null) MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());
```

The arguments you pass to the event will depend on the declaration of the event. To give you a little more background, an event is just a compiler trick. When an event such as

```
public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;
```

is compiled it will look like

```
protected ChangedEventHandler _change;
public ChangedEventHandler Change
{
    add { _change += value; }
    remove { _change -= value; }
}
```

so anything inside where it is declared will use `_change`, while anything outside will use `Change`. In other words, inside where it is declared, it is just a delegate, and all the normal rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example to call event....

```
// event_keyword.cs
using System;
public delegate void MyDelegate();   // delegate declaration

public interface I 
{
   event MyDelegate MyEvent;
   void FireAway();
}

public class MyClass: I 
{
   public event MyDelegate MyEvent;

   public void FireAway() 
   {
      if (MyEvent != null)
         MyEvent();
   }
}

public class MainClass 
{
   static private void f() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires.");
   }

   static public void Main () 
   {
      I i = new MyClass();

      i.MyEvent += new MyDelegate(f);
      i.FireAway();
   }
}
```

There is [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which may helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your sample vikky. It is helpful for me. A event is invoked by the class which including the event. Thank you for the information you provided. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

To resuse the event you just need to attach event with the you control for example .

```
buttonone.Click+= event1;
buttonTwo.Click+= event1;
```

Fore more details have look : [C# Event Implementation Fundamentals, Best Practices and Conventions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/event_fundamentals.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined the delegate, you need to define when to call the event. I mean you can call the event at assignment of any value to the specific variable.

here is the example of defining the delegate with the same variable class.

```
public class callbackdel : EventArgs
{
    public readonly string resp = null;

    public callbackdel(string s)
    {
        resp = s;
    }
}    

public delegate void WorkerEndHandler(object o, callbackdel e);
```

Now in the control you are using, you need to add this method.

```
public void OnWorkEnd(object o, callbackdel e)
{
        WorkEnd(o, e);
}
```

after creating method and defining the delegate, you can fire the event from any of the delegate simply by calling the method.

```
OnWorkEnd((object)this, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an Event you first have to declare it:

```
// Create some custom arguments for the event
public class SampleEventArgs
{
    public SampleEventArgs(string s) 
    { 
        Text = s; 
    }
    public String Text {get; private set;} 
}

// Define a class that uses the event
public class EventPublisher
{
    // Declare the delegate 
    public delegate void SampleEventHandler(object sender, SampleEventArgs e);

    // Declare the event.
    public event SampleEventHandler SampleEvent;

    // Wrap the event in a protected virtual method
    // to enable derived classes to raise the event.
    protected virtual void RaiseSampleEvent()
    {
        // Raise the event by using the () operator.
        if (SampleEvent != null)
            SampleEvent(this, new SampleEventArgs("Hello"));
    }
}
```

You can then subscribe to the event:

```
 EventPublisher publisher = new EventPublisher();
            publisher.SampleEvent += new EventPublisher.SampleEventHandler(SampleEventHandler);

public void SampleEventHandler(object sender, SampleEventArgs args)
        {

        }
```

Your event handler will be called when `EventPublisher` executes `RaiseSampleEvent()`